# Store the results of a sql minus statement in a list variable

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two databases and I want to see the difference between some of their tables, so far I have got to this point

```
declare
  type arraytype is table of varchar2(50) ;
  namearray arraytype := arraytype(); 

BEGIN
  SELECT table_name 
  BULK COLLECT INTO namearray
  FROM all_tables 
  where owner = 'DB1name' 
  AND table_name IN ('table1','table2','table3', .....);

  FOR i IN 1..namearray.count LOOP
     SELECT ID FROM CONCAT('DB1Name.', namearray(i))
     MINUS
    SELECT ID FROM CONCAT('DB2Name.', namearray(i));
  END LOOP;
END;
```

what I am lacking now is to store the result of the minus statement into a list. I am using Oracle 18 db and my user can only query and not create anything.

How can I do this?

cheers,

es

Comment: `FROM CONCAT('DB1Name.', namearray(i))` will not work. You need to use `EXECUTE IMMEDATE` or build a dynamic cursor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build the statement dynamically and then execute it using `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`, something like:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_sql CLOB;
  v_ids SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST;
BEGIN
  FOR r IN ( SELECT MIN(owner) AS owner1,
                    MAX(owner) AS owner2,
                    table_name 
             FROM   all_tables 
             WHERE  owner      IN ( 'DB1NAME', 'DB2NAME' )
             AND    table_name IN ('TABLE1','TABLE2','TABLE3')
             GROUP BY table_name
             HAVING COUNT(owner) = 2
           )
  LOOP
    IF v_sql IS NULL THEN
      v_sql := 'SELECT ID FROM ';
    ELSE
      v_sql := v_sql || ' UNION ALL ';
    END IF;
    v_sql := v_sql || '('
          || 'SELECT id'
          || ' FROM ' || DBMS_ASSERT.ENQUOTE_NAME(r.owner1, FALSE) || '.' || DBMS_ASSERT.ENQUOTE_NAME(r.table_name, FALSE)
          || ' MINUS'
          || ' SELECT id'
          || ' FROM ' || DBMS_ASSERT.ENQUOTE_NAME(r.owner2, FALSE) || '.' || DBMS_ASSERT.ENQUOTE_NAME(r.table_name, FALSE)
          || ')';
  END LOOP;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_sql);
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql BULK COLLECT INTO v_ids;
  
  FOR i IN 1 .. v_ids.COUNT LOOP
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_ids(i));
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Alternatively, use the query (and copy-paste additional tables as needed):

```sql
SELECT id
FROM   (
  SELECT id FROM DB1Name.Table1
  MINUS
  SELECT id FROM DB2Name.Table1
)
UNION ALL
(
  SELECT id FROM DB1Name.Table2
  MINUS
  SELECT id FROM DB2Name.Table2
)
UNION ALL
(
  SELECT id FROM DB1Name.Table3
  MINUS
  SELECT id FROM DB2Name.Table3
)
```